# Why does different integer declaration change the results?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, variable-declaration

The problem exists in the first nested loop, where the results doesn't go out as expected, I'm working on CodeBlocks 17.12

What I did to try fix the problem is to change "int s[n]" to "long long s[n]" and it worked good, but unfortunately for another inputs I need to put it back "int s[0]" to work well.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    do
    {
       cin >> n;
    }
    while (n < 1 || n > pow(10, 5));
    int s[n];
    int m = 0;
    //Inputs number of friends in each group.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            cin >> s[i];
        }
        while (s[i] < 1 || s[i] > 4);
        if (s[i] == 4)
        {
            m++;
            s[i] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            /* Hold each number of members in the groups and add them to the rest numbers to check if it would be equal to 4 then
            if two numbers equal to 4, both numbers will be 0s. */
            for (int a = 0; a < n; a++)
            {
                if (a != i)
                {
                    if (s[i] + s[a] == 4)
                    {
                        m++;
                        s[i] = 0;
                        s[a] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << m << endl;
}

}
```

The input is "78
2 2 2 2 3 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2"
As 78 in first line and the rest in the second line.
The expected result : 38    [when "long long s[0] works well"]
The result : 39 [when "int s[0]" give this result]
That's the problem if I didn't explain well in the code :https://codeforces.com/contest/158/problem/B

Comment: Please make an [mcve] and include all necessary information including the test cases in the question itself.

Comment: when you do `idiv++`  then you return `idiv` you are returning the copy of `idiv` that is not incremented yet. Why would you do the post increment yet the post increment is destroyed immediately after the if statement? You have not used it anywhere in your whole code. Did you mean to us a preincrement?

Comment: @Onyambu hey, near the end of main function line 70, there is this line "m += roundtoP( z, 4);" which works fine actually, I don't really understand you?
"when you do idiv++ then you return idiv you are returning the copy of idiv that is not incremented" Actually it returns the incremented value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array size should be between 1 to 100000. Based on User input your creating the array.

```
        do
        {
            cin >> n;
        } 
        while (n < 1 || n > pow(10, 5));
```

While running your code I'm getting an Error In this code `long long s[n];` because n should be const value. so i changed that code.

**Solution :**

```
long long* s = new long long(n);
```

Once Array is created. Your taking the input from User to store the array. that value is between `1 to 4` your checking multiple condition.

1. if given value is `4` then `m++` and `s[i] = 0` or
2. in else part given value + array element check if that value is equal to 4 then assign `s[i]` and `s[a] =0`

Comment: It seems that I have a  problem with declaring arrays, I want to ask several questions:
First: I use codeblocks which actually avoid many problems in the code, so do you recommend something better?
Second: Under which topic I can study more for this problem.
Third: what's "new" in long long refer to?

Comment: 1. better use visual studio.                                                                                                                                                    2. Array declaration and Basic topics in c++                                                                              
3. new is a memory allocation operator.